# how to update an existing database from another database in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, strapi, mongodb-atlas

I would like to know how to update an existing database from another database in mongodb ... but previously a little of context.

I've created an app with strapi and mongodb ( more precisely with mongo atlas) and I'm using 2 environments, development and production(with a development and production database). At the beginning, i've created the development database and i copied/cloned this database to another database with this command (previously I created the db file with `mongodump`)

`mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-url>" --archive="app-development.db" --nsFrom='app-development.*' --nsTo='app-production.*`

After creating this database i carried on with my develop into the development database, and now i would like to import the development database into the production database...but  i got the error `continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection`
So I don't know how can i re-import the databases, and also i would like to know if this way is a good practice or i should do it in a different way

Comment: Maybe `mongoexport` and `mongoimpoirt` would be better in your case.

Comment: I will try it but  I only one copy the collection and not the document from one database to another database